# Use Custom Library in Controller of Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, nusoap, laravel-controller

I wanted to use nusoap_client class so decided to add [nusoap](https://github.com/econea/nusoap) library to my laravel project. Like other libraries, i used github readme page to get it done.

```
composer require econea/nusoap:^0.9.6
```

This library was added to `../vendor/econea/nusoap/src/nusoap.php`. Then i wanted to use it in my controller but i tried many ways to use it like below :

```
use SoapClient;
use vendor\econea\nusoap\src\nusoap.php;
use nusoap.php;
use nusoap;
```

I even tried to load library in autoload in **composer.json** file without any luck. laravel kept repeating same error.

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\nusoap_client' not found

I appreciate any help given that suggests a way to use nusoap_client in my code or the correct way to use the library in my laravel project.
thanks.

my code:

```
$client = new nusoap_client('example.com/api/v1', 'wsdl');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper syntax at the top of your controller should be:

```
use nusoap_client;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because this class does not contain a valid namespace.

So, you need to import this PHP file into your script using the require function.

To solve this in laravel, just import your file using composer like:

```
"autoload": {
    "files": ["path/to/vendor/script"]
}
```

With autoloaded file, you can instantiate the class in any script class of your project.

But, I don't think that's a good way to work with modern PHP. 
I know another library that works with SOAP: https://github.com/artisaninweb/laravel-soap

It's a wrapper for SoapClient http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.soapclient.php, a PHP core class that provides a soap client.

Hope my contribution can be useful and my english understandable.